# how to calculate area of rectangle using class by taking user input in __init__

Tags: python, class, user-input

"""
As you can see i am trying to find out the area of rectangle using class in which i want to take user input but something is wrong in line 22
"""
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod #just practicing about abstractmethod which i learn today

```
class shape(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def printdetail(self):

        return 0
class Area(shape):
    def __init__(self,length,breadth):
        self.length = length
        self.breadth = breadth
    def printdetail(self):
        return self.breadth * self.length
    @classmethod
    def userinput(cls):
        length = int(input("enter a length")) #taking user input as length of rectangle
        breadth = int(input("enter a breadth "))#taking user input as breadth of rectangle
rect= Area.userinput()
ans=rect.printdetail()
print(ans)
```

"""error-
ans=rect.printdetail()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'printdetail'
"""

Answer (score 1):

Your class method is getting the input, but never creates the instance of `Area` to return.

```
@classmethod
def userinput(cls):
    length = int(input("enter a length")) #taking user input as length of rectangle
    breadth = int(input("enter a breadth "))#taking user input as breadth of rectangle
    return cls(length, breadth)
```